# .contains() not finding multiple lines in java

Tags: java, string, file, contains

im trying to do string .contains() for specific lines on text
im reading in lines of a file using Files.readAlllines.
im trying to do

```
Path c1=Paths.get(prop.getProperty("testPWP"));
     List<String> newLines1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (String line : Files.readAllLines(c1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
if (line.contains("return test ;\r\n" + "       }")) {
    newLines1.add( line.replace("return test ;\r\n" +
            "       }", "return test ;\r\n" +
            "       }*/"));
}


         else {
                newLines1.add(line);
             }
         }
         Files.write(c1, newLines1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

im basically trying to comment the } after the return statement but the contains function not recongnizing it as its in new line in the file.
Any help on this issue?

Comment: `Files.readAllLines()` splits the input by line separators (i.e. two lines of text are returned as two strings). Your search pattern contains a line terminator and can therefore never be found - you will have to search for the first and the second part in two different strings.

Comment: @ThomasKläger but i cant search on seprate as there are other } in the file thats why i did as whole string

Comment: can u show any suggestion with my above code to read and modify then write to the same file @ThomasKläger

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replaceable parameter to replace the regex.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String find = "return test ;\r\n" + "       }";
        String str = "Hello return test ;\r\n" + "       } Hi Bye";
        boolean found = str.contains(find);
        System.out.println(found);
        if (found) {
            str = str.replaceAll("(" + find + ")", "/*$1*/");
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
Hello /*return test ;
       }*/ Hi Bye
```

Here `$1` specifies the [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html), `group(1)`.

In your program, the value of `str` can be populated as follows:

```
String str = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

In case your Java version is less than 11, you do it as follows:

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Comment: this wont work in my case as im using Files.readAllLines to read the file in then do the check for strings

Comment: @dave - I've added an update using which you can read the content of the file into `str`.

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash  would i not need to iterate through this string? also how to perform the write to the same file that is read in with this new approach?

Comment: @dave - It depends on your requirement. If you want to process the content line by line, then you will need to iterate; otherwise, you do not need to do so. **A note on iteration:** If you know `Stream` API, it will be easier for you to process each line e.g. `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding).stream().map(...)...`

Comment: have a look at my question i edited it this is what i have for iteration issue with this is i can do .contains() for 2 lines as mentioned in Q, how to alter this to read with new method?

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, `Files.readAllLines` reads all lines and returns a list in which each string represents a line. To accomplish what you are trying to do, you either need to read the entire file into a single string, or concatenate the strings you already have, or change your approach of substitution. The easiest way would be to read the entire contents of the file into one string, which can be accomplished as follows:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path to file")));
```

or if you are using Java 11 or higher:

```
String content = Files.readString(Paths.get("path to file"));
```

Comment: i want to write to the file as well as after modified it, can u show a demo if u can